# How to append to a SQL command?

Tags: php, sql, command, append, addition

Just wondering is this how you append to an SQL statement that has yet to be executed?

```
$select = $select & "ORDER BY orderDate ASC";
```

Comment: This is not SQL. This may be PHP and string manipulation

Comment: You will likely want a space before ORDER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that's not very good practice with direct strings concatenations, if there is some possibility of switching from one DB  driver to another, like, PostgreSQL doesn't supports backtics for column names (i.e. ``` SELECT ``field`` from table ```).

So, probably, it's better to use some query building frameworks for that.

Like, `Laravel` uses it's own builder, called `Eloquent`. In `Eloquent` you build your's requests like this:

```
$q = DB::table("table_name")
       ->select(["name", "sum(a) as total"])
       ->where("age", ">", 20);
```

then fetch data like this:

```
$data = $q->get();
```

and can modify query after that and fetch again:

```
$beforeFourty = $q->where("age", "<", 40)
                  ->take(10)
                  ->get();
```

and so on...

Comment: Thankyou very much for showing me this, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language. 
In straight SQL (not creating a SQL statement in something like PHP) it would look something like:

```
SET @select = @select + ' ORDER BY orderDate ASC';
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, just wasn't sure whether it was the & or a +

Comment: This is doing it in straight SQL though.  If you are doing it in something like PHP you have to follow their string appending syntax.